# Save VM cost when using Rest API deploying models for online inference

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

Save VM cost when using Rest API deploying models for online inference
ADB allows us to deploy the models for online inference through a REST API. To that aim ADB creates a VM dedicated to serve a specific model. Data Scientist can create and deploy several models for testing online inference, thus the cost can rapidly grow uncontroled and unnecessarily because those newly created VMs are running all the time.

It is possible to shut them down after certain period of inactivity?

Comment: Welcome! It's a bit difficult to understand your question (plus there's no actual programming question - this is more infrastructure doc info). What is "ADB"? Is that supposed to be Azure databricks? If so, that should be spelled out. Also: no idea what you're trying to shut down. If it's Databricks clusters, I suggest looking at the documentation, which fully covers things like timeouts/shutdowns.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the questions is more related to model serving. 
In the documentation about model serving it says the following
• The cluster is maintained as long as serving is enabled, even if no active model version exists. To terminate the serving cluster, disable model serving for the registered model.



In order to try to save cost, I want to ask if exist anyway to start/stop those Jobs clusters via Scheduling feature in Azure DataBricks? 

Or is possible enable those features in clusters from model serving

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft answered me that, in a future Azure Databricks version, Model serving will be improved – using containers instead of using virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can enable auto scaling in Azure-Databricks(job cluster), this would terminate all except min # of workers(would be kept alive).

https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#enable-and-configure-autoscaling